Get a list of futures trading pairs on Binance using ccxt
I used the following code but it returns a list of trading pairs with the suffix /USDT:USDT. I only want to get the futures trading pairs. What code should I use to avoid getting the spot trading pairs by mistake?
markets = await asyncio.to_thread(self.exchange.fetch_markets)

            
            futures_pairs = [
                market['symbol']
                for market in markets
                if market.get('symbol').endswith("USDT") and
                   market['info'].get('contractType') == 'PERPETUAL'
            ]

I need to get a list of futures trading pairs on Binance using ccxt. What code should I use to getting the future trading pairs?
